# What's the sqlite's cost model?

Tags: sqlite, query-optimization

I found only "SQLite uses a cost-based query planner that estimates the CPU and disk I/O costs of various competing query plans and chooses the plan that it thinks will be the fastest." from documents of documents, is there any paper or book specify the cost function with more details ? thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only the [source code](http://www.sqlite.org/cgi/src/dir?name=src) (`where.c`).
The query planner details are tweaked in every version.